# Configure IMAP server using java

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-mail, imap

Is there a way I can enable my spring boot application to listen to IMAP protocol and operations?

(OR)

I can build an independent IMAP server that listens to IMAP and do the IMAP operations using `java.mail`

Comment: Check this https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mail.html

Comment: It is working as an email client and reads mal from the external server. I want to enable my app to listen to IMAP operations